# ngModel values are not getting displayed in controls in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a model which is an array element and it's corresponding HTML view is as below:

```
<div *ngIf="flag" >
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered  table-mc-light-blue">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>col 1</th>
                   <th>col 2</th>
                   <th>col 3</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of collection;">
                 <td>{{item.col1}}</td>
                 <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.col2" #input="ngModel" name="input-{{i}}">
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
```

On some conditions, I am inserting new elements using splice.Please find below code

```
this.collection.splice(LastIndex, 0, ...newArray);
```

The problem is that after insertion the previous ngModel values are not getting displayed for certain records.
I inspected the element and found **ng-reflect-model** set to previous values, but I couldn't see the values in input controls.

Please find the image [image: html View]

Comment: Question seems a bit unclear to me at least, could you try and recreate the issue in a plunker and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by modifying my logic as below:

```
    let tempCollection = this.collection.slice();

    //empty the list       
    this.collection = [];

    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); //needed to reflect changes

    //insert elements in the list
    tempCollection.splice(LastIndex, 0, ...elements);

    //push once again to collection
    this.collection.push(...tempCollection);
```

Instead of directly manipulating the **collection**, I copied it into the temporary variable called **tempCollection** for manipulation and cleared the **collection** variable.

Once manipulation is done, I pushed entire **tempCollection** to **collection**.
I used **this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()** to reflect the changes, once I had cleared collection.

Comment: thank you ... I was getting very frustrated until I read your solution. Not sure why Angular is getting confused

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have same problem and it save my time. Could you explain to me why this is so?

Comment: @VõĐạiThắng, I am not actually sure. Might be Angular's change detection has been built that way.